# Construct a tuple with arbitrary number of types, all constructable from a single type, and non-default-construcible

Tags: c++, stdtuple, parameter-pack

I have a tuple

```
using MyTuple = std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, ... FooN>;
```

and want to construct MyTuple like this

MyTuple foo{Foo1{x}, Foo2{x}, Foo3{x}, ... FooN{x}};

- `FooK` is not default constructible
- `N` is not known at write-time. Thus I cannot hardcode a list like the one above.

What I have is

```
Enum::Tuple<EnumType, EnumTypeTraits> foo;
```

Which have been constructed from advice from here: [Create template pack from set of traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505297/create-template-pack-from-set-of-traits), like so: https://github.com/milasudril/libenum/blob/master/libenum/tuple.hpp.

Do I need to add some ctor to `Enum::Tuple` to make it work?

Here is `Enum::Tuple` for reference:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<ContiguousEnum EnumType,
             template<EnumType>
             class EnumItemTraits,
             class T = std::make_integer_sequence<
                 std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>,
                 Size<EnumType>::value  // NOTE: calling distance here triggers ICE in gcc 10.2
                 >>
    struct make_tuple;

    template<ContiguousEnum EnumType,
             template<EnumType>
             class EnumItemTraits,
             std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>... indices>
    struct make_tuple<EnumType,
                      EnumItemTraits,
                      std::integer_sequence<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>, indices...>>
    {
        using type =
            std::tuple<typename int_to_type<EnumType, EnumItemTraits, indices>::type...>;
    };
}

template<ContiguousEnum EnumType, template<EnumType> class EnumItemTraits>
class Tuple: private detail::make_tuple<EnumType, EnumItemTraits>::type
{
public:
    using Base       = typename detail::make_tuple<EnumType, EnumItemTraits>::type;
    using index_type = EnumType;
    template<index_type index>
    using traits = EnumItemTraits<index>;

    using Base::Base;

    static constexpr auto size() { return std::tuple_size_v<Base>; }

    template<index_type i>
    using tuple_element = std::tuple_element_t<distance(begin(Empty<EnumType>{}), i), Base>;

    template<index_type i>
    constexpr auto const& get() const
    {
        return std::get<distance(begin(Empty<EnumType>{}), i)>(base());
    }

    template<index_type i>
    constexpr auto& get()
    {
        return std::get<distance(begin(Empty<EnumType>{}), i)>(base());
    }

private:
    Base const& base() const { return *this; }

    Base& base() { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: Could you show how you intend to use the class? (Something like a [mcve], even though it might not compile). It's not fully clear to my why `std::tuple` isn't good enough: It's already variadic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want something like:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct tag{};

template <typename Tuple> struct tag_from_tuple;
template <typename Tuple> using tag_from_tuple_t = typename tag_from_tuple<Tuple>::type;

template <typename... Ts> struct tag_from_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = tag<Ts...>;
};


template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> make_tuple_from_impl(const T& t, tag<Ts...>)
{
    return {Ts{t}...};
}

template <typename Tuple, typename T>
Tuple make_tuple_from(const T& t)
{
    return make_tuple_from_impl(t, tag_from_tuple_t<Tuple>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4e6f5ce13cd80b2)